# three.js Box3.min and max localToWorld

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am just stuck right now.
i have several Vectors (Vertices) which are parts of bigger objects and i am generating two Box3's with it:

```
    obj1box = new THREE.Box3().setFromPoints(buffer1); //buffer 1 and 2 are arrays of vectors
    obj2box = new THREE.Box3().setFromPoints(buffer2); //vectors were part of a huge object
```

With these Boxes i want to compute distances between these boxes, but both boxes are in localspace. So with console.log(obj1box), the box.max and min parameters are in local space but i need them in world space. How can i convert the boxes into worldspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem:

```
    obj2.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    obj2box.applyMatrix4(obj2.matrixWorld);
```